# Efficiently write log file on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, logging, qfile

I want to write log files. My application could be run on Linux and Windows. I've pretty much figured out how to do it for the former, thanks to this example:

```
void SyslogMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    Q_UNUSED(context)

    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
      switch (type) 
      {
      case QtDebugMsg:
         #ifdef __linux__
           syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Message (debug): %s", localMsg.constData());
          #elif _WIN32
            // WRITE INTO FILE
          #else
          #endif
          break;
      // etc.
      }
}

int main()
{
    // Install our message handler.
    qInstallMessageHandler(SyslogMessageHandler);
    // Send some messages, which should go to syslog.
    qDebug("Debug log message from Qt test program");
}
```

[source](https://www.ics.com/blog/whats-new-qt-560-logging-syslog-and-journald) (2nd example)

However, I am wondering what would be the fastest way for Windows? Is using `QFile` or `QTextStream` an efficient way for writing this kind of information?

I was thinking about storing everything in a simple `QString` and then put everything in a file when the app closes or crashes (in the latter case, is that possible?).

Comment: A crash is final, so you'll want to stream the log data into the log file. Having an open file handle isn't much overhead, so I don't really see performance concerns with your proposed approach.

Comment: Any risks of having corrupted information if a crash prevents the application to close the file? Anyway I think I'll use `QTextStream` if it doesn't consume too much power. Note that the app would run continously for weeks.

Comment: You can always use a `try` and `catch` block in `int main` to be sure the log file gets closed. The `QFile` and `QTextStream` instances won't use any cycles unless and when you're writing to them.

Comment: The experience with log intensive system is that you have to use log write thread. Linux syslog does that for you but in case of Windows you need to create an object running in the other thread and send log text to write to file. Of course the log file should be kept open but make it flush with every log line, though. QTextStream can be enclosed in scope on stack for that.